# Integration involving product of piecewise constant function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I have to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{T}f(t)m(t)\,dt.$$
where
$$m(t)=\exp[3+5\exp(3+\log t_i)], \quad t_{i-1}<t<t_{i}$$
is a piecewise constant function, and 
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{t+3}.$$

How can I solve that? Shall I take the the value of $m(t)$ for each interval and then multiply it with $\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}f(t)\,dt$ and finally take a sum of the products?

Need your suggestion.

Comment: Why is $m(t)$ piecewise constant?  I see $t$ in the exponent, so it doesn't look constant to me.  Do you want a $t_i$ in the exponent?  If so, then your suggestion is a reasonable approach.

Comment: @MichaelBurr , You mean, when $m(t)=\mathrm{exp}^{3+5* \mathrm{exp}^{(3+logt_i)}}$, then my suggestion is a reasonable approach?

Comment: Yes, it is a reasonable approach in that case.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you.:)